# How to efficiently save a stat that updates continuously in java?

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I am building a basic java discord bot to learn the language. I wanted to increment a counter for each member. Each time they send message on a server I want to increment this counter, like server points. The issue is as I am so new to the language I don't know a good way to do this efficiently. Could anyone give me any pointers?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I usually use that code to save when necessary, but not too frequently:

```
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class DelayedSaver<T> {



    /*
     * STATIC
     */

    public interface SaveLambda<T> {
        void run(T pValue);
    }

    static public void sleep(final int pMS) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(pMS);
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) { /* ignore */ }
    }



    /*
     * TEST
     */

    static public void main(final String[] args) {
        final SaveLambda<String> saveAction = p -> {
            System.out.println("Saving value [" + p + "]");
            // actually you would write to a file or database here
        };

        final DelayedSaver<String> ds = new DelayedSaver<>(saveAction, 3000, false, false); // will run in its own thread
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            sleep((int) Math.pow(Math.random() * 80, 2)); // sleep 0 - 6.4 seconds, longer times are more improbable but possible

            final String newEventValue = "TestString " + ((int) (Math.random() * 100));
            System.out.println("Received new value: " + newEventValue);
            ds.update(newEventValue);
        }
        System.out.println("Test ended.");
        ds.dispose();
    }



    /*
     * OBJECT
     */

    private final LinkedBlockingQueue<T> mQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    private final SaveLambda<T> mSaveLambda;
    private final int           mUpdateMS;
    private final Thread        mWorkingThread;
    private final boolean       mWaitForSavingThread;

    private volatile boolean mDisposed;



    /**
     * @param pSaveLambda The code to be run to save the latest value
     * @param pUpdateMS The time in milliseconds for a consecutive check
     * @param pUseDaemonThread If true, does not need a call to {@link #dispose()} to end thread. If false, might will not save latest value.
     * @param pWaitForSavingThread If saving takes long time, set to true, to prevent race conditions on resources
     */
    public DelayedSaver(final SaveLambda<T> pSaveLambda, final int pUpdateMS, final boolean pUseDaemonThread, final boolean pWaitForSavingThread) {
        mSaveLambda = pSaveLambda;
        mUpdateMS = pUpdateMS;
        mWaitForSavingThread = pWaitForSavingThread;

        mWorkingThread = new Thread(() -> runLoop(), getClass().getName());

        if (pUseDaemonThread) mWorkingThread.setDaemon(true);
        // daemon threads automatically end when all essential threads end, so not dispose() necessary.
        // but this might prevent the latest value from being saved

        mWorkingThread.start();
    }



    public void update(final T pValue) {
        if (mDisposed) throw new IllegalStateException("This service is already disposed and cannot accept any more values.");
        mQueue.add(pValue);
    }

    public void dispose() { // manually end the thread
        mDisposed = true;
        mWorkingThread.interrupt(); // send interrupt signal to daemon thread
    }

    private void runLoop() {
        System.out.println(getClass() + " started.");
        // this will also save the latest value if dispose() was called
        while (!mDisposed) {
            sleep(mUpdateMS);

            final T latestValue = grabLatestValue();
            if (latestValue != null) {
                final Thread savingThread = new Thread(() -> mSaveLambda.run(latestValue), getClass().getName() + " Saving Thread"); // do NOT set daemon=true here
                savingThread.start();
                if (mWaitForSavingThread) try {
                    savingThread.join();
                } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                    System.err.println("Error while waiting for Saving Thread:");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println(" (" + getClass().getName() + " checked, but no values present, skipping.)");
            }

            if (Thread.interrupted()) break;
        }
    }

    private T grabLatestValue() {
        T value = mQueue.poll();
        while (true) {
            final T value2 = mQueue.poll();
            if (value2 == null) break;
            value = value2;
        }
        return value;
    }

}
```

I hope that's what you're after. Like in the example (main method), call `ds.update(newEventValue);` each time someone sends a new message.